# Product image on customer account dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, product-images, image, customer-account

On our customer account dashboard, we want to display the product image inside the order.
We want to display the image before the product title.

What code do I need to add to the file

```
app/design/frontend/theme/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
$item = $this->getItem();

$product = $item->getParentId() ? $item->getParent()->getProduct() : $item->getProduct();

echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is what i used

```
<?php
// Load the product object
if($_item->getProductType() == 'configurable') {
    $_product = $_item->getProduct();
} else {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
}

// If no valid product could be loaded, use the default placeholder image for the product
$imgUrl = '/skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg';

// If a valid product has been loaded, use that product's thumbnail

if($_product->getId() && $_product->hasThumbnail()) {
    $imgUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(80, 120);
} 
?>
```

while, we have to consider the layout of the table, particularly when you hope it can be responsive.

the colspan=4 take trouble to us, while, we can change it by local.xml by following:

```
    <sales_order_view translate="label">
    <!--
        remove colspan=4 
    -->
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" class="a-right"</value></action>
        <action method="setValueProperties"><value>colspan="3" class="last a-right"</value></action>
    </reference>

</sales_order_view>
```

reference:
https://mobweb.ch/2014-08-12-magento-showing-product-images-on-the-order-overview-in-the-admin-panel/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349592/make-all-store-images-the-base-small-and-thumbnail-images-in-magento